# Enable wallpaper scrolling for HTC Sense 4+

Tags: htc-sense, wallpaper

My htc one x just got updated to HTC Sense 4+.
Just yesterday, there was another update but I don't quite know what that update was for. Anyway, with sense 4+, the wallpaper doesn't scroll when I go to different panels. Furthermore, I don't quite like carousel either.

I thought the widgets have become a lot more stylish, though.

How do I enable wallpaper scrolling with sense 4+ now? 
If that is not possible, how do I roll back to HTC sense 4?

I don't like Go Launcher because, I think, the widgets are not as good as the HTC ones; so I'd rather not replace sense with something else.

Is this somehow possible at all, please? 
I am willing to root my phone, if needed, to get the wallpaper scrolling back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HTC One X too, and I hadn't noticed yet that wallpaper scrolling is not working anymore. After some searching in the settings, I haven't found the solution to your problem. So I think that I have to conclude that there is no option to restore this functionality.

Reverting back to previouse Sense versions is not an option as far as I know. Rooting is an option, but I guess that this will not fix the problem, though I cannot really say for sure it will or will not.

Comment: that's really sad, I love the wallpaper scrolling. I hope they bring it back.. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Play app called [Landscape Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lwp.superluminar.swallpaper); it works. I think we can't have the scrolling effect because of the "carousel" effect of the panels.

Comment: Please add a link to the app. :)